# Tombstone records from Kafka Connect

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to configure Kafka Connect (Source) to generate a tombstone record?

I have a table recording 'delete' events.   I can populate this to a topic and write some code to forward tombstone records to other topics as needed, but if I can have the JDBC source connector generate the tombstone record for me, I can skip the ode part.  I'm not see a way to set the value in kafka source connect to 'null'.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it can because it would only be able to know which columns are nullable, not the whole record. It might be possible with an SMT in Connect, though

Comment: Thanks; I was able to produce the tombstone record using Drop.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to answer your own question below.

Comment: @DebbieR could you post your smt config here?

Answer (score 0):

I think, as @Debbie suggested, we will be able to create the Tombstone record using "Drop" Kafka Connect Transformation.

Here is the working code snippet from JDBC Source Connector configuration :

```
"transforms": "dropValueAndForceOptionalSchema",
"transforms.dropValueAndForceOptionalSchema.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Drop$Value",
"transforms.dropValueAndForceOptionalSchema.schema.behavior": "force_optional"
```

So, the configuration will drop the value from the message and if the schema for the value isn’t already optional, the transformation will forcefully overwrite the schema to become optional.

```
ksql> PRINT 'local-CONTINENTS';

Key format: AVRO or KAFKA_BIGINT or KAFKA_DOUBLE or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
rowtime: 2023/08/22 10:30:11.165 Z, key: {"CONT_CODE": "EU"}, value: <null>, partition: 0
Value format: AVRO
rowtime: 2023/08/22 10:33:11.167 Z, key: {"CONT_CODE": "AS"}, value: {"CONT_CODE": "AS", "CONT_NAME": "ASIA", "CONT_REFUPD": 1692700360103}, partition: 0
```

Hope it might help!

Thanks.