# Tombstone messages from Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, change-data-capture

I am building a pipeline to import table data from one database to another using [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) and [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect). I can't use `log-based CDC` (and such great things like [debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium)), so I have to use `query-based CDC` and [`JDBC Source Connector`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html).

[`JDBC Sink Connector`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html) is used to import from Kafka to the target database. This connector [supports deletes](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/pull/641):

> A record with *null* value is considered a *tombstone event* and result in deleting the corresponding row in the destination table.

So if I were to use `Debezium`, I could use the `tombstones.on.delete` option to emit tombstones, however, in the case of the query-based CDC approach, I need to use a special column to mark deleted rows.

Is there any solution for transformation messages (representing "soft deletes") into tombstone events (or, in other words, to set value of such messages to null)? Maybe I could use some kind of conditional [Kafka Connect SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html) or something else?

Overall, is it a good idea to turn *"soft"* deletes into real ones?

Thanks in advance!

---

*Similar questions:*

- [Delete events from JDBC Kafka Connect Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044641/delete-events-from-jdbc-kafka-connect-source)
- [Tombstone records from Kafka Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512030/tombstone-records-from-kafka-connect)

Comment: I don't immediately see anything wrong with an SMT

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for reply! So I can just write my own SMT for this purpose, right?

Comment: Based on what I understood, then yes

Comment: Is this not possible with predicates and the standard SMTs?